# Run express server when react app runs on the web

Tags: reactjs, express, server

I have a basic react app which makes a call to an express server. In my localhost i can run the server with the command nodemon server.js and then my react app successfully makes calls to the server (which sends emails, it all works fine)

The issues is i must run the server everytime i want to let my app contact my server, but when i will deploy my app to my web hosting, the client using the website cannot run the server, needless to say. So my question is what can i do to resolve this?

I've just started backend dev so go easy please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find a place to **host** your Node.js backend. There the service will continuously run and will be accessible from the internet. You could either rent a server or go with a serverless approach (like Netlify or countless other providers).

Comment: ok any docs on how to deploy the server on netlify? Can i do it with vercel though? I've used that in the past to host websites.